# How to access discovery.svc service, if it needs authorisation (MS Forefront)?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, gateway

I have an URL like https://crm.xxxx.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc and I want to discover an organisation with my client. But if I open this URL in a browser window, I will get an authorisation screen:

[image]

I get an exception, If I try to add this url on client to following method as parameter "url":

```cs
ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<T>(new Uri(url));
```

Exception:  *Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "https://crm.xxxx.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl".*

or

Exception:  *Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "https://crm.xxxx.com/XRMServices/2011/Organisation.svc?wsdl".*

How to pass through this authntication?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's anything to do with CRM, but to do with the network setup. I would suggest speaking to the network administrators.